# Why does selecting columns from pandas read_excel give different formats?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Pandas returns different results given the datasets. Anyone know why?

I have two datasets, one with three columns and the other with two.

`abc.xls : Table_Name(str), Test1(str), Test2(str)`

`xyz.xls : Table_Name(str), Test2(str)`

```
import pandas as pd
data1= pd.read_excel("abc.xls")
data2= pd.read_excel("xyz.xls")

table1= data1[data1['Table_Name'].str.strip() == "TEST"]
table2= data2[data2['Table_Name'].str.strip() == "TEST"]
```

`table1.Description` will give me just the text field of the description

`table2.Description`, however, will give me the index and the text field. So I would have to do `table2.Description.values()[0]` to get the text field that I want.

This is rather inconsistent, while there are ways around it, I would rather like to know what is causing this issue.

Comment: I don't think it's related to `read_excel`. Can you show `data1.head()` and `data2.head()`?

Comment: Post too the actual command and output (don't tell us, show us) as each column of a pandas DataFrame column is a pandas Series and should include index.